# Google Identity Toolkit - Facebook Integration

Tags: google-identity-toolkit

Can somebody help me?

I don't know how to follow Step 4 item 2 (c, d and e) in Google Identity Toolkit start App [Guide](https://developers.google.com/identity/toolkit/android/quickstart#optional_step_4_facebook_integration).

**Optional) Step 4: Facebook integration

2. Register your app on Facebook

   c. Fill Facebook app ID/secret in Google developer console.

   d. Conifgure the App Domain. If you are testing locally, this should be https://localhost.

   e. Add another platform, this time for Web. Enter your widget URL in the Site URL field.**

I could not find where in the Google Developer Console I should "fill Facebook app Id/secret"
And the folllow items d and e I have no idea.

I am a beginner, so sorry for asking nonsense.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok,

I'm dumb. kkk

I found the answer.

overview > Identity Toolkit API > settings > facebook

Thanks!!!